# Using Report Server's Report Builder to edit SSRS report deployed in SharePoint foundation

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Can we use Report Server's Report Builder to edit SSRS reports deployed in SharePoint Foundation. Just like we edit report in Report Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, l was doing that in Sharepoint Foundation 2013 site last week.

[image: Screenshot showing the menus l use to access report builder from within sharepoint environment]

Comment: Bob, how did you do that?

Comment: added screenshot of menus, just left hand mouse click to go through the menus.  If this is not what you mean let me know

Comment: Bob, this is SharePoint 2013 enterprise. I am talking about using Report Builder in SharePoint Foundation 2013.

Comment: Ok l could be wrong, l am not the sharepoint admin for these sites. As l understand for this client there are two flavours of sharepoint running at different URL's. A foundation instance (which l used for the screenshots) and another which l think is enterprise. Tomorrow morning l will check with the sharepoint admin and confirm.

Comment: Hi checked with our Sharepoint admin this morning.  The screenshots about are from the foundation 2013 site.  What you will need to do is set up reporting services for the instance. Then you should be able to do what l have shown above.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation Bob. As far as i know, report builder is not available in foundation 2013. Could you guide me what steps should i take to get Report Builder work in Foundation 2013.

Comment: Have you installed reporting services? (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492276.aspx)